# Multi-Head Attention in ViT

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, transformers

I need help to understand the multihead attention in ViT. Here's the code I found from [GitHub](https://github.com/lucidrains/vit-pytorch/blob/main/vit_pytorch/vit.py):

```
class Attention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, heads = 8, dim_head = 64, dropout = 0.):
        super().__init__()
        inner_dim = dim_head *  heads
        project_out = not (heads == 1 and dim_head == dim)

        self.heads = heads
        self.scale = dim_head ** -0.5

        self.attend = nn.Softmax(dim = -1)
        self.to_qkv = nn.Linear(dim, inner_dim * 3, bias = False)

        self.to_out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(inner_dim, dim),
            nn.Dropout(dropout)
        ) if project_out else nn.Identity()

    def forward(self, x):
        qkv = self.to_qkv(x).chunk(3, dim = -1)
        q, k, v = map(lambda t: rearrange(t, 'b n (h d) -> b h n d', h = self.heads), qkv)

        dots = torch.matmul(q, k.transpose(-1, -2)) * self.scale

        attn = self.attend(dots)

        out = torch.matmul(attn, v)
        out = rearrange(out, 'b h n d -> b n (h d)')
        return self.to_out(out)
```

I'm confused with the `dim` and `dim_head` here.

For example, I want to input an image (PyTorch) as `batchsize, channels, width, height = x.size()`

Should my `dim` value be `dim = batchsize * channels * width * height` or should it be the `dim_head`?

Or

```
dim  = batchsize * channels * width * height
dim_head = channels
```

Also, in `def forward(self, x):`, what is the representations of `b n (h d)`?

Last one, pytorch have a multihead attention [module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html). written as:

```
multihead_attn = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim, num_heads)
attn_output, attn_output_weights = multihead_attn(query, key, value)
```

Can I use that in image data as input?